# NSMutableArray insertObject:(id) atIndex:int inserting a void ptr

Tags: c++, cocoa, nsmutablearray, objective-c++

In my application, i have a mix of C++ and Objective C++ code, at one place, i need to insert pointer of c++ class object to NSMutableArray , but i am getting NSINvalidArgument exception, 
Can anyone guide me, how can i insert void pointer to NSMuatableArray

This is what i have tried ,

```
pArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithCapacity:myList.size()];

Node *node = myList.getHead();

int idx =0;
void *ptr = nil;
while ( node ) {
    [pCTArray insertObject:(NSObject *)node atIndex:idx];
    node = node->getNext();
    idx++;

}
```

Is there any otherway to insert it into the MutableArray, 
the possible workaround i made is : having store index link this

```
[myArray insertObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:idx] atIndex:idx];
```

and this array i would be using in all NSTable/NSOutliveVIew delegate method , i need to pick the index and get the element from the linklist, but worried because of performance, as too many function call would be needed,

Is this any bug in Cocoa or i am making anything wrong ?

Comment: This does not look like C++ to me.

Comment: @John It's objective-C++, C++ with all the features of objective-C or vice versa.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

NSArrays expect to hold objective-C objects conforming to the `NSObject` protocol. If you wish to wrap a pointer, use NSValue:

```
[myArray insertObject:[NSValue valueWithPointer:node] atIndex:idx];
```

You are manually responsible for all memory management of that pointer, as objective-C can't reference count it in the usual way.

Answer (score 1):

`NSMurableArray` only accepts Objective-C objects (hence the argument type of `addObject:` being `id`).

Are you on the Mac or iOS? If you're on the Mac, You might want to look at `NSPointerArray`.

You might also be able to be `CFMutableArray` with custom callback functions, but I haven't tried this myself.

Comment: I've never used NSPointerArray, but it does look like a good fit for this problem. The memory management helper functions would probably be useful, I don't think NSValue has the equivalent. Also, I think it's safe to assume Mac from "NSTable/NSOutliveVIew"

Comment: Yeah, that should've clicked, shouldn't it? I looked for a Mac or iPhone tag and didn't see one.

Comment: Hi, I tried with NSPointerArray, following is my code snippet \n pCTArray = [[NSPointerArray alloc]initWithOptions:NSPointerFunctionsObjectPersonality]; then set the size [pCTArray setCount:10]; after that try to insert 10 objects in while loop but i am always getting EXEC_BAD_SIGNAL , am i missing something

Answer (score 0):

A third option is `NSPointerArray`.